# Zend Framework 2 and Concrete5 session

Tags: php, zend-framework2, concrete5

Having a project developed in Zend Framework 2 and with concrete5 integrated, how can I access  in concrete5 session created with zend framework 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your ZF2 session within a `user` namespace, for example, you will be able to access it like this: `$_SESSION['user']['username']`. Below is a more complete example.

```
// Storing session data within Zend Framework 2
$session = new \Zend\Session\Container('user');
$session->username = 'Andy0708';

// Accessing session data within concrete5
$username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
```

Alternatively, you should be able to simply use the `Zend\Session` component within concrete5. Although one of the goals of Zend Framework 2 is to avoid dependencies, I have not checked if there are any dependencies to the `Zend\Session` component. Otherwise, having autoloading in place, this would not be a problem. It has been a while since I have worked with concrete5, so I am unable to provide you with details of how to handle autoloading and such in concrete5, but since you have already integrated concrete5, you should have handled this already. So, you should also be able to do something like this if you prefer the ZF2 way:

```
// Assuming that autoloading is in place
$session = new \Zend\Session\Container('user');
$username = $session->username;
```